# Prestashop how to add Code to Hook with Module

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

i am trying to add code to a Hook, which is called whenever a customer is successfully registered in our shop. In the Prestashop doc is shown that the Hook should be "actionCustomerAccountAdd".

The Code of my Module looks like the following:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;
 
class SendEmail extends Module
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'SendEmail';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0';
    $this->author = 'Philip Zadeh';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.4', 'max' => '1.7');

 
    parent::__construct();
 
    $this->displayName = $this->l('SendEmail');
    $this->description = $this->l('Activate to enable activation Emails for new Customers.');
 
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
 
    if (!Configuration::get('SendEmail_NAME'))      
      $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
  }
    
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install()
            && $this->createRequiredDBTables()
            && $this->registerHook('actionCustomerAccountAdd');
    }
    
    public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params)
    {
        $this->logger->info('Hook action customer account add fired');
        echo 'hook fired';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

The first part is just basic settings of the Module.
At the install function i am adding the Hook.

To be honest i am not quite sure what createRequiredDBTables is for (i just tried this code line from a different post but it didn't worked aswell)

At the hook function i am trying to add the code to the hook and basically logging some text.

As you can assume unfortunately nothing happens when a new customer account is created...

I would be glad if someone could help me out

Best regards,
Liam

*EDIT actionObjectCustomerAddAfter tryed this hook aswell, also not working

Comment: Try to enable debug and clear your cache, the install and call method looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $this->createRequiredDBTables() line from the install method.

As far as I can see, there is no such method in the module at the moment, so the installation probably doesn't run correctly.

Or you can add this method to the module, but I don't think you need it.

```
public function createRequiredDBTables(){
   //create DB tables, or whatever
   return true;
}
```

So remove that line, and try to reset/install your module again.
Your install method shoduld look like this:
public function install()

```
  {
        return parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('actionCustomerAccountAdd');
    }
```